# How to provide error handling in MS Access for an Excel spreadsheet import

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import, error-handling

I'm trying to import a whole bunch of Excel files separated by the name of a client for the year to date. Now, these files contain many records, and there is a different worksheet for each day of a month. Each individual part of the code seems to work. I've tested it individually before. However, there is no spreadsheet if the day is a weekend or holiday. I handled the weekends. But the On Error Resume Next doesn't seem to be dealing with the holidays correctly. Can anyone point me in the right directions?

Notes: Client and path will be hard-coded for...reasons. The extraneous message boxes are for testing purposes. Naming conventions for spreadsheets is _#. If you know a better way to do any of this, please feel free to let me know.

```
Public Function importer()
Dim file As String, path As String, i As Integer, datevar As Date, month As     Integer, fDate As Variant

path = "path"
file = Dir(path & "*client*")

DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM [table]")


Do While file <> ""


    If file Like "*2018*" Then
        month = GetMonth(file)
        MsgBox (path & file)

        For i = 1 To 31
        If IsDate(month & "/" & i & "/2018") = True Then
        datevar = CDate(month & "/" & i & "/2018")
            If IsDate(datevar) = True And datevar < CDate("8/8/2018") Then
                fDate = Weekday(month & "/" & i & "/2018", vbMonday)
                If fDate < 5 Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "table", path & file, True, "_" & i
                End If
             End If
        End If
        Next i

     Else
        MsgBox ("No")
    End If
    file = Dir
Loop


End Function

Public Function GetMonth(file) As Variant
    Dim monthnumberx As Integer
        Select Case True
            Case file Like "*January*"
            monthnumberx = 1
            Case file Like "*February*"
            monthnumberx = 2
            Case file Like "*March*"
            monthnumberx = 3
            Case file Like "*April*"
            monthnumberx = 4
            Case file Like "*May*"
            monthnumberx = 5
            Case file Like "*June*"
            monthnumberx = 6
            Case file Like "*July*"
            monthnumberx = 7
            Case file Like "*August*"
            monthnumberx = 8
            Case file Like "*September*"
            monthnumberx = 9
            Case file Like "*October*"
            monthnumberx = 10
            Case file Like "*November*"
            monthnumberx = 11
            Case file Like "*December*"
            monthnumberx = 12
            End Select
     GetMonth = monthnumberx
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd break up your `importer` procedure into 2 parts.

1. `ProcessExcelFiles` which does your directory file loop.
2. `ExcelFileImport` that imports the file.

*Then the error trap will log a record for that individual file.*

I recommend reading [**Clean Code**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001GSTOAM), it really improved my coding skills. One of the concepts it covers is if the procedure does more than one *thing*, it needs to be split into separate procedures. Also, name the procedures what they do e.g. `importer` would be better named `ExcelFileImport` or in a module `Excel` as a procedure `FileImport`.

```
Public Sub ProcessExcelFiles()
On Error GoTo ErrTrap
Dim file As String, path As String, i As Integer, datevar As Date, month As Integer, fDate As Variant
Dim filePath As String

    path = "path"
    file = Dir(path & "*client*")

    DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM [table]")

    Do While file <> ""
        If file Like "*2018*" Then
            month = GetMonth(file)
            'MsgBox (path & file)

            For i = 1 To 31
                If IsDate(month & "/" & i & "/2018") = True Then
                datevar = CDate(month & "/" & i & "/2018")
                    If IsDate(datevar) = True And datevar < CDate("8/8/2018") Then
                        fDate = Weekday(month & "/" & i & "/2018", vbMonday)
                        If fDate < 5 Then
                            filePath = path & file
                            ExcelFileImport filePath, i
                        End If
                     End If
                End If
            Next i

         Else
            MsgBox ("No")
        End If
        file = Dir
    Loop

ExitProcedure:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    Select Case Err.number
        Case Is <> 0
            ErrorLog "MyModule", "ProcessExcelFiles", Err.number, Err.description, file
            Resume ExitProcedure
        Case Else
            Resume ExitProcedure
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub ExcelFileImport(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal index As Integer)
On Error GoTo ErrTrap

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "table", filePath, True, "_" & index

ExitProcedure:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    Select Case Err.number
        Case Is <> 0
            ErrorLog "MyModule", "ExcelFileImport", Err.number, Err.description, filePath
            Resume ExitProcedure
        Case Else
            Resume ExitProcedure
    End Select

End Sub

Private Function GetMonth(ByVal file As String) As Variant
    Dim monthnumberx As Integer
        Select Case True
            Case file Like "*January*"
            monthnumberx = 1
            Case file Like "*February*"
            monthnumberx = 2
            Case file Like "*March*"
            monthnumberx = 3
            Case file Like "*April*"
            monthnumberx = 4
            Case file Like "*May*"
            monthnumberx = 5
            Case file Like "*June*"
            monthnumberx = 6
            Case file Like "*July*"
            monthnumberx = 7
            Case file Like "*August*"
            monthnumberx = 8
            Case file Like "*September*"
            monthnumberx = 9
            Case file Like "*October*"
            monthnumberx = 10
            Case file Like "*November*"
            monthnumberx = 11
            Case file Like "*December*"
            monthnumberx = 12
            End Select
     GetMonth = monthnumberx
End Function

Public Sub ErrorLog( _
  ByVal Module As String _
, ByVal procedure As String _
, ByVal number As Variant _
, ByVal description As String _
, ByVal fileName As String)
On Error GoTo ErrTrap
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  Creates a record of the error
' Example:  ErrorLog "MyModule", "ExcelFileImport", "404", "Error Message Here...", "C:\Temp\test.xlsx"
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO [ERROR_LOG] (UserName, ComputerName, ErrorDateTime, ModuleName, ProcedureName, ErrorNumber, ErrorDescription, FilePath) VALUES " _
    & "('" & Environ("UserName") & "', '" & Environ("ComputerName") & "', '" & CStr(Format(Now(), "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM")) & "', '" & Module & "', '" & procedure & "', '" & CStr(number) & "', '" & description & "', '" & fileName & "');")

ExitProcedure:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    Select Case Err.number
        Case Is <> 0
            Resume ExitProcedure
        Case Else
            Resume ExitProcedure
    End Select

End Sub
```

> FYI, you'll have to create an `[ERROR_LOG]` table.

```
CREATE TABLE ERROR_LOG 
(
  UserName Text(255)
, ComputerName Text(255)
, ErrorDateTime Text(255)
, ModuleName Text(255)
, ProcedureName Text(255)
, ErrorNumber Text(255)
, ErrorDescription Text(255)
, FilePath Text(255)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the book recommendation. My main job title isn't as a developer, I'm just writing scripts to be more efficient. But I'm being asked to do this stuff more and more, so maybe I should learn to do this right.

Comment: It turns out that this doesn't quite work. So basically, as it loops through, it comes across February 19th, a holiday, and breaks the code. No error is logged in the table and it doesn't resume.

Comment: Can you post a list of file names to test with?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that I didn't error trap the `GetMonth` function.